# Preventing javascript function from accidentally using the global window

Tags: javascript

If I wanted to create a javascript "class" with two properties, I'd probably do something like:

```
var Person = function (firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
```

I could then create a new person as follows:

```
var p = new Person("John", "Doe");
console.log(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
```

At this point, everything is great. However, if someone accidentally (or purposely) calls the following:

```
Person("Mary", "Smith"); // without "new"
```

All of the sudden, `firstName` and `lastName` are part of the global window context, and could potentially screw up the whole page.

```
console.log(window.firstName); // logs "Mary"
```

Is there a good way to try to prevent this, when building the `Person` "class"? Obviously if someone wanted to break something in javascript, they can do it, but I'm just looking for the best practice.

I could throw something like this at the top of the class, but I don't know if that's a good answer:

```
if (this === window) {
    console.log("You are fail");
    return;
}
```

Comment: You will pretty quickly discover the error with minimal testing because if the function is called without `new`, it will return `undefined` rather than the expected object. Better to fail early and hard than try to hide errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if `this` is `instanceof Person`

```
var Person = function (firstName, lastName) {
    if (!(this instanceof Person))
        throw "Person constructor called without \"new\"."
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
```

---

Or have it recall the constructor appropriately.

```
var Person = function (firstName, lastName) {
    if (!(this instanceof Person))
        return new Person(firstName, lastName)
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
```

---

Another possibility is to have your function run in strict mode. This will cause `this` to be `undefined` in that scenario, causing a TypeError, but only in supported implementations.

```
var Person = function (firstName, lastName) {
    "use strict";
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
```

Comment: I do like this better than my last snippet comparing `this` with `window`.

Comment: I like your second example as well - makes it a lot more forgiving. Not always the right thing to do, but that's definitely a good idea.

Comment: I'll have to research `"use strict"` a little more - that looks pretty interesting.

Comment: @JoeEnos: It works nicely if you have a known number of parameters. It gets a little more complex if not. And "strict mode" is a great way to enforce better/safer coding. It's lexically scoped, so you could actually make your code globally strict.