# How to not use the `new` operator in JS API?

Tags: javascript

So I came across [this article](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/post/something-new) where Mr. Baranovskiy basically says that people shouldn't have to use the `new` operator to use your api. I have created [this basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/K8cha/8/) which lets you create instances of `colorBox` with this line of code `var box = new colorBox(node, options);`

How could implement what I have in the example without using the `new` operator?

JS:

```
var colorBox = function(node, options) {
    this.setSize = function(){
        node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
        node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    }
    this.setColor = function(color){
        node.style.backgroundColor = color || options.color;
    }
    this.setSize();
    this.setColor();

}

var node = document.getElementById('thing1');
var options = {
    color: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}

var box = new colorBox(node, options);

setTimeout(function(){
    box.setColor('blue');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: The article suggests that the API you expose to an API user should not require the user to use `new`. *Your code* that *implements the API* can use `new`. Basically, anytime you expect the user to create an object, write a function that creates the object for the user.

Comment: create a new instance inside of colorBox and return it out of colorBox(node, options), or use return this.

Comment: @apsillers If I had code that implemented an API without using `new` I wouldn't have a question.

Comment: @sherlock You misunderstand apsillers. He's saying that the article says that its advice only applies if you are writing an API for someone else. If someone else needs to use the classes you write (e.g. you provide `colorBox` as part of a jQuery replacement), then you shouldn't use `new`. But if you are just writing code for your own app/website, or private code *inside* a library that is not part of the public API, then there is no problem. Your current code might be fine according to the article, even though it uses `new`, as long as it is not creating a library for others to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I don't agree with the article - I think `new` is a perfectly reasonable way of writing code, and makes it clear that you're creating an instance of a "class", like any object-oriented language.

But...

Take a look at the second approach on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508200/111266), which shows how to have a function which will return a new instance if the caller leaves off `new` (if `this` is not an instance of the "class", then the caller left off `new`, and `this` is probably the global window). That's one way of not requiring the user to type `new`, while still safely returning a new instance each time.

```
var colorBox = function(node, options) {
    if (!(this instanceof colorBox))
        return new colorBox(node, options);

    // do the rest of your constructor stuff
};
```

Comment: +1 because I like the statement of intent `new` provides, but personally I think an optional `new` is worse than none at all

Comment: @AlexK I agree. I personally would probably choose the first approach on that linked answer, which throws an error back out if you forget `new`. This (hopefully) would mean the developer will catch it and fix it early if they forget it.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap all of your uses of `new` inside functions that call `new` for you. That way, a user of your API never needs to use `new` -- they just call the function that returns the result of the `new` operation:

```
function makeColorBox(node, options) {
    return new colorBox(node, options);
}
```

That said, I personally don't think requiring the use of `new` is really a big deal when designing an API.

*That* said, you [sometimes might want to avoid `new` for other reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198267/why-is-the-use-of-constructors-discouraged-when-creating-prototypes) and use `Object.create` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A solution completely without `new` would look like this:

```
function colorBox(node, options) {
    var box = {
        setSize: function(){
            node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
            node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
        },
        setColor: function(color){
            node.style.backgroundColor = color || options.color;
        }
    };
    box.setSize();
    box.setColor();
    return box;
}
```

Here the object to be returned is created using curly braces `box = { .... }`

Comment: That won't be friendly with prototypes or `instanceOf`

Comment: Just to clarify, the author of the referenced article never suggests that `new` should be excised from your code entirely: "*I am not saying that using new operator is a bad idea, it’s an essential operator, but asking me to use it with your API is a bad idea.*"